# Flutter não encontra pubspec.yaml quando executo run

Tags: flutter, dart

Fiz a instalação do dart + flutter pela primeira vez hoje, fiz a configuração orientada pelo Getting Start do próprio site oficial, porém na hora de dar RUN no projeto, aparece esse erro:

> No pubspec.yaml file found.

Já tentei executar o `flutter upgrade` porém ainda assim não resolveu, no `flutter doctor` não aparentou problemas e também é a ultima versão instalada.

Como posso resolver?

[image: erro flutter]

Comment: Verifique se o diretório que vc está é a raiz do projeto. Para isso pode simplesmente abrir a pasta pelo `explorer` do windows ou então utilizar o comando `dir` no terminal e ver os arquivos que estão listados. O erro que está recebendo fala que vc não está na raiz do projeto.

Comment: Foi isso mesmo @LeonardoPaim, acabei me confundindo com as pastas e por isso o erro. A dica da lista de arquivos no terminal foi importante, não sabia dessa ferramenta. Obrigado!

Comment: Postei como resposta para que possa ser consultada mais facilmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O diretório onde está rodando o comando não é o diretório raiz do projeto. O comando `flutter run` precisa ser executado em uma pasta que contenha os arquivos do projeto flutter e o `pubspec.yaml` é um desses arquivos.

Uma dica que pode ser usada é listar os arquivos da pasta. No Windows por exemplo, pode facilmente verificá-los através do comando `dir`.

Quando posicionar dentro da pasta o comando funcionará.